# Video/Audio file analysis - meta data, similar to MediaInfo

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, media-player, media

I usually use MediaInfo to look into my media files to see the duration of the video/audio tracks within the file. I believe MediaInfo looks at meta data of the file ( headers ) rather than the actual filestream, probably due to speed. I want a tool that actually goes through the file to work out the duration of the video/audio tracks within the media file, rather than just telling me what the headers tell me.

The reason I need this is because I have an instance of a media file which is not reporting the correct audio track duration. Example: I have two files, an audio file and a video file, vid1.mxf and aud1.mxf, these are the same length. I 'stich' these together using FFMPEG and because of storage failure/network issues the audio track in the resulting file is short, **however** it does not report as short within MediaInfo. When I listen to the file however it is clearly short, the network/storage device must have become inaccessible during the 'stitching' toether. The audio and video input files are on different storage devices.

I have in the past used the C# library https://github.com/naudio/NAudio which does this sort of this, however it only works with singular .wav files, and not files where there is a video inside the container too ( .mxf ).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using ffprobe, but larger the file, the more time it will take.

**Step 1** Extract raw info

```
ffprobe input.mxf -select_streams v -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration_time -of compact

ffprobe input.mxf -select_streams a -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration_time -of compact
```

This produce a readout where the lines look like this

```
packet|pts_time=4.480000|duration_time=0.040000
```

**Step 2** Calculate duration

For both the video and audio streams, you want at look at the `pts_time` on the first line and the `pts_time` and `duration_time` on the last line. Stream duration is then

```
pts_time(last line) + duration_time(last line) - pts_time(first line)
```

---

There is a duration field as well, but it doesn't record the value in all container formats.

```
ffprobe input.mxf -show_entries stream=duration
```

Comment: Actually no, this doesn't work. It decodes the audio track in it's entirety (same duration as video ) and shows exactly the same duration as MediaInfo does. I tried something similar by just decoding it with ffmpeg and copying the audio stream, output to null, it still decodes the full 30 seconds ( video ), even though when listening to the audio the audio stops at around 25 seconds.

Comment: Then there are null audio samples for the last 5 seconds. The audio and video streams are independent essences. ffprobe isn't generating packet entries where there are none. Try this: extract an audio excerpt `ffmpeg -i video -t 5 -vn aud.mp4` where `5` is a value smaller than video duration. Then `ffmpeg -i video -i aud.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a joined.mp4`. Now run the Step 1 commands and compare the final pts_time values.